# Any continuous map $f:S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to show that a continuous function from the sphere $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

I searched about this question online and it seems that it can be solved using some properties of cell complexes but I'm not familiar with this notion, is there another method to solve this problem?

Comment: To be clear, given a continuous map $f : S^n\to\mathbb{R}$, are you asking why there exists a continuous map $g : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g|_{S^n} = f$? If so, this can be shown by writing such a $g$ down.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese exactly! But I wanted to know if there is a solution using algebraic topology?

Comment: There is. Can you see why $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ extends to a map on $D^{n+1}$?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't! I know that the disc is contractible but I don't know how to use this !

Comment: A map $f: S^n \to Y$ extends to a map $D^{n+1} \to Y$ if and only if $f$ is nullhomotopic. Are you familiar with this result?

Comment: I didn't heard before of this result (I will work on it). The map in the question is clearly nulhomotopic hence (using the result) can be extended to the disc.

Comment: Then it suffices to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is homeomorphic to the open ball in order to extend the resulting map to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ right?

Comment: Instead of using the fact that the open disc is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, consider $S^n$ as the equator of $S^{n+1}$. Can you use what we've discussed so far to see how $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ extends to $S^{n+1}$?

Comment: I think yes! Now that we have extended $f$ to $D^{n+1}$ we can use the fact that $D^{n+1}/\partial D^{n+1}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n+1}$ we get the extended map $f: S^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ . and  since $S^{n+1}$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we get the result, is this correct?

Comment: No, because if you construct the sphere that way, you're not extending the map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (you are crushing that $S^n$ to a point). Instead, note that viewing $S^n$ as the equator of $S^{n+1}$, it bounds two copies of $D^{n+1}$, the southern hemisphere and the nothern hemisphere.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, Got it!  Many thanks to you for this discussion, it was of a great help! (If you have time you could write this as an answer I will accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the discussion with the OP in the comments above into an answer as requested.

---

Recall that a map $f : S^n \to Y$ extends to a map $D^{n+1} \to Y$ if and only if $f$ is nullhomotopic. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, every map $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is nullhomotopic. Viewing $S^n \subset S^{n+1}$ as the equator, it
bounds two copies of $D^{n+1}$ (the southern hemisphere and the northern hemisphere), so $f$ extends to a map $\hat{f} : S^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$. Restricting $\hat{f}$ to the complement of the north pole $N$ and precomposing with the inverse of stereographic projection away from $N$ yields a map $g : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g|_{S^n} = f$.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(r,\theta):=r\cdot f(\theta),\,f(0):=0$$Is one such extension.

Answer (score 2):

FShrike's answer gives a nice explicit formula for extending from $S^n$ to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.  Let me also point out that this is true in much greater generality, with no cell-complexes or anything of the sort.

If $C\subseteq X$ is a closed subset of a normal topological space $X$, then every continuous function $f\colon C\to \mathbb R$ may be extended to a continuous function $\tilde{f}\colon X\to \mathbb R$, by the [Tietze extension theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem)

Since $S^n$ is closed in the normal space $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ the result follows.